# cygwin kill process issue

Tags: bash, shell, cygwin

I am trying to run a shell script in Cygwin, but I am having problem with passing variables to the subshell !!

I have a very simple script that actually takes the PID of a process and from there I would like to kill the process from within the script.

```
# my_proc_kill.sh
#
export c=$(ps -W | grep -ir behave | sed 's/\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/')
echo $c
#1
/bin/kill -f $c     
#2                  
sh -c '/bin/kill -f ${c}' "$c" 
#3       
sh -c '/bin/kill -f $@' _ "$c"        
#4
e=$(taskkill /PID $c)
```

I tried to kill the process four different ways, and non of them worked !

I don't know why (#1) and (#4) work just fine if I call them directly within a Cygwin terminal, but not when I run "my_proc_kill.sh".

One other thing I noticed, is that for (#4) if I replace "$c" with the actual process number, and then run "my_proc_kill.sh", then that will work. So, it looks like the variable value "$c" is not passed to "taskkill" !!
How can I modify the code, so that the taskkill will know about variable "$c" ?!?

But shouldn't the PID be fixed for a specific process, as long as I haven't killed the process, regardless of what shell I am accessing that process ID?

Please advise how to get around this?

Here is the error messages I get, when I run the script:

```
5040
kill: illegal pid: 5040
kill: illegal pid: 5040
kill: illegal pid: 5040
kill: illegal pid:
ERROR: Invalid query
```

Why "kill" sees this as an illegal pid?
But when I use the same PID number (in this case 5040) in the Cygwin terminal, it works? (the following is okay)

```
$/bin/kill -f 5040
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. replace `echo $c` with `echo .$c.` to make sure $c doesn't contain blanks or so. 2. what does kill -f? unknown on my ubuntu 10. 3. doesn't `ps -W | grep -ir behave...` also print the pid of grep? 4. why grep -r? 5. what's ps -W?

Comment: I think those are not the issue. Because inside the script I just replaced $c with the actual PID number (for my case is 5040) and I still got the exact same errors as before. In other words, I changed my script to (/bin/kill -f 5040) still the same thing. I also tried (/bin/kill/ 5040) still the same error. But when I type this exact expression (/bin/kill -f 5040) in a Cygwin command line, it kills the process, and everything looks okay.

Answer (score 0):

Your output seems to indicate that you're trying to kill the same PID 5 times.

I ran a modified version of your script using red-hat's cygwin (CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW64):

```
#!/bin/bash

export c=$(ps -W | grep -ir notepad | sed 's/\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/')
echo $c

/bin/kill -f $c
```

I didn't get any odd behaviors.  A successful call to kill will output the PID (which is shown on the first line).

If repeat the last line 4 times I'll get error messages.

Other than that, there's a chance that the last PID is a child process that terminates when the parent process does - like a tree-kill.

As an alternative suggestion, I've used the "dirty" way by executing taskkill with the /F argument in addition to the /IMAGE option to match the exe name instead of specifying PID.  Examples provided in:

```
taskkill /?
```

Comment: I am using the exact Cygwin version (CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW64), and I just removed everything else from my script, and left it just the way you have it (with only three lines), but again, after running it, I get "kill: illegal pid: 11132", but 11132 is the correct PID, once I do (/bin/kill -f 11132) in the command line, everything works fine ! Would you know what might be going on?

Comment: UPDATE:
After a long time, I just resolved the issue. The issue all along was the carriage return character. Once in GVIM I set ":e ++ff=unix", I saw all the carriage return characters, and once I got read of them, then everything started working just fine.

Comment: @user2201373: Maybe it would be nice to add your solution to the question or post it as answer for easier finding.